# Gettin an error syntax error unexpected token < in json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, wcf, twitter-bootstrap-3

hi I have a code with wcf json format and I'm getting an error "syntax error unexpected token < in json" I dont knowwhat to do please help me, thanks in advance.`public string Update(string details)
        {
            string connectionString = GetConnectionString();

```
        //Details = Details.Replace(',', '.');
        String[] UpdateUserDetails = new String[15];
        // insertUserDetails = Details.Split('~');
        using (OleDbConnection connection1 = new OleDbConnection())
        {
            connection1.ConnectionString = connectionString;
            connection1.Open();

            OleDbCommand command = connection1.CreateCommand();

            //Check user exits
            OleDbCommand cmdcheck = new OleDbCommand();
            cmdcheck.CommandText = "select count(*) from usermaster where Username='" + UpdateUserDetails[0] + "'";
            cmdcheck.Connection = connection1;
            int iReturn = Convert.ToInt16(cmdcheck.ExecuteScalar());
            if (iReturn <= 0)
            {
                string sqlUpdate = "UPDATE usermaster SET UserID= '100', UserName='" +
                 details.Split('~')[0] + "', Password = '" + details.Split('~')[1] + "', FirstName = '" + details.Split('~')[2] + "',LastName = '"
                    + details.Split('~')[3] + "', Email = '" + details.Split('~')[4].Replace('#', '.') + "', MobileNo = '" + details.Split('~')[5] + "', UserType = '"
                    + details.Split('~')[6] + "', UserGroup = '" + details.Split('~')[7] + "', PlantLocation = '" + details.Split('~')[8] + "', Department = '"
                    + details.Split('~')[9] + "', Designation = '" + details.Split('~')[10] + "',Approved = 'No' ";

                OleDbCommand cmdUpdate = new OleDbCommand();
                cmdUpdate.CommandText = sqlUpdate;
                cmdUpdate.Connection = connection1;
                int x = cmdUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmdUpdate.Dispose();
                if (x == 1)
                    return "User Updated Successfully";
                else
                    return "User Updation failed";
            }
            else
            {
                return "User Name already exists";
            }
        }
    }`
```

Comment: Share the code, json, something to better understand the problem.

Comment: That error generally means that the endpoint is returning HTML or XML from the request, not the JSON you expect. Check the responseText as it's most likely caused by an error on the server

Comment: Ihave shared both json and wcf codes @MilanChheda

Answer (score -2):

Well, you could try phyton 3 instead:

EXAMPLE:

```
   #!/usr/bin/python3
   import sys

   if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    name = sys.argv[1]
    print("Hello", name)
```